# Is it possible to run multiple command with remote command option in putty?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty, server-administration

I want to run multiple commands automatically like sudo bash, ssh server01, ls , cd /tmp etc at server login..
I am using Remote command option under SSH in putty.

I tried multiple commands with delimiter && but not working.

[image]

Comment: And any solution to pass the password as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a some information lacking in your question.

You say you want to run `sudo bash`, then `ssh server01`.

Will sudo prompt for a password in your remote server?

Assuming there is no password in sudo, running bash will open another shell waiting for user input. The command `ssh server01` will not be run until that bash shell is exited.

If you want to run 2 commands, try first simpler ones like:

```
ls -l /tmp ; echo "hi there"
```

or if you prefer:

```
ls -l /tmp && echo "hi there"
```

Does this work?

If what you want is to run ssh after running bash, you can try :

```
sudo bash -c "ssh server01"
```

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me. Which commands did you try? What do you see on the console?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the command is expected to be a program name followed by parameters, which will be passed directly to the program. In order to get `&&` and other functionality that is provided by a command line interpreter such as `bash`, try this:

```
/bin/bash -c "command1 && command2"
```

Comment: @AmanAggarwal: Try double-quotes (I edited the posts), which I just verified that works on my machine.

Comment: Not working...
Actually I want to run "sudo bash && ssh server01 "
Is there any issue for sudo bash or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried what I suggested in my previous answer.

It is possible to run 2 simple commands in putty separated by a semicolon. As in my example I tried with ls and echo. The remote server runs them and then the session closes.

I also tried to ssh to a remote server that is configured for not asking for a password. In that case, it also works, I get connected to the 2nd server and I can run commands on it. Upon exit, the 2 connections are closed.

So please, let us know what you actually need / want.

Comment: i want to automatically run two commands with putty connection..
First command sudo bash needs password and then ssh to another server.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute two consecutive commands in PuTTY using a regular shell syntax. E.g. using `;` or `&&`.

---

But you want to execute `ssh server01` in `sudo bash` shell, right?

These are not two consecutive commands, it's `ssh server01` command executed within `sudo bash`.

So you have to use a `sudo` command-line syntax to execute the `ssh server01`, like

```
sudo bash ssh server01
```