# Putty: trying to send multiple commands to remote server but only the first is executed

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, putty

I am using Putty on windows machine to connect to Unix servers.

I'm trying to follow along [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858114/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-command-with-remote-command-option-in-putty) where some answers there suggest that in order to send multiple commands to the remote server, the commands have to be separated by a semicolon. However, in my case it appears that only the first command is being accepted while the rest are left ignored.

The command sequence that I try to send to the remote server is `bash ; cd /nts/data ; ls` (I tried to issue these commands with and without double quotes, still the same result):

[image]

I issue `bash` as the first command because when I login to the remote server, the default prompt is `bash~$` and when i type `bash` and hit Enter the prompt changes into `user@webserver02~$`.

How to send multiple commands to the remote server at the login via Putty?

Comment: The solution to this is in [my (downvoted) answer to the question you have linked yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30858114/850848#30861824).